# Отправка данных на почту с помощью Post запроса

Tags: java, android, post, sendmail, httpurlconnection

Мне нужно отправить данные на почту (точнее на сервер, а там сервер на почту) POST запрос c параметрами. Помогите пожалуйста как это сделать, код ошибок не выдает, не могу понять, что именно не так. Ответ от сервера не нужен, просто отправить данные.

Вот код:

```
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            String paramss = "name=" + params[0] + "@number=" + params[1];
            URL url = new URL("http://177.177.177.237:86/send/");

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", paramss);
            connection.connect();

            Log.e("TAG", "Opa " + connection.getResponseCode());


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

В итоге ошибок код не выдает, на почту ничего не приходит, в логах Opa дает код 400

Еще вариантом было вписать параметры в URL, но тоже не помогло

```
URL url = new URL("http://177.127.177.237:86/send/name=" + params[0] + "@number=" + params[1]);
```

Comment: А что Вы делаете в `connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", paramss);`?

Comment: А что нужно туда вставлять, да лажанулся. "text/plain" ?

Comment: Могу быть не прав, но это поле необязательно заполнять. Другое дело, что больше-то ничего Вы и не передаете.

Comment: Прописал "text/plain" теперь на почту хоть сообщение приходит, но поля пустые, параметры не передались

Comment: Если не заполнять, как же тогда параметры передавать

Comment: `Content-Length` -- это размер (число, в байтах) того, что Вы передаете.

Вот Вам хороший пример: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4206094

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL("http://177.127.177.237:86/send");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
// формируем параметры :
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstParam", paramValue1));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("secondParam", paramValue2));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("thirdParam", paramValue3));

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getQuery(params));
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();

conn.connect();// только здесь передаем
```

и конвертириуем параметры в UTF-8:

```
private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: `NameValuePair` это что извиняюсь, у меня красным светит

Comment: @T.Kudaibergen, кастом класс

Comment: NameValuePair не устаревший способ?